# Implementing an Interface on a class with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm developing a Blazor app and somewhere I'm implementing an interface:

```
public class UserData : IUserData
{
    private readonly ISqlDataAccess _db;

    public UserData(ISqlDataAccess db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public void SomeFunction ()
    {
        ...
    }
}
public interface IUserData
{
    void SomeFunction();
}
```

While on `.razor` I can do: `@inject IUserData UserData;` and `((UserData)UserData).SomeFunction();`; I'm failing to discover how to do it on `.cs file`.

```
//There is no such constructor and If I create a new one, then I won't get the _db dependecy injection
IUserData userDate = new UserData();
userDate.SomeFunction();
```

**Edit**

So now, when I'm calling the method from the `.cs file`, the app freezes; it doesn't throw an error and I am able to refresh the page, so it seems it's stuck on the call to the db; but if I call it from the `.razor` it works flawlessy.

**.cs**

```
public AccountService(IUserData userData)
{
    _userData = userData;
}
...
public async Task<bool> Validate(string userId, string password)
{
    ...
    try
    {
        List<UserModel> users = new List<UserModel<();
        users = await _userData.GetUsers();
        //NEVER GETS HERE
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

**.razor**

```
@inject IUserData _db;

@code {
    private List<UserModel> users;
    ...
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        users = await _db.GetUsers();
    }
    ...
```

**UserData**

```
    public class UserData : IUserData
    {
        private readonly ISqlDataAccess _db;

        public UserData(ISqlDataAccess db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public Task<List<UserModel>> GetUsers()
        {
            string sql = "Select *from dbo.Users";
            return _db.LoadData<UserModel, dynamic>(sql, new { });
    }
    ...
}
```

**IUserData**

```
    public interface IUserData
    {
        Task<List<UserModel>> GetUsers();
        ...
    }
```

**Edit2**
It turns out I was missing an await when calling Validate() service, and thus not running it asynchronous.

Comment: You need to inject it. What is the containing class?

Comment: Did you configured injection in your startup.cs?

Comment: @Fildor By containing class you mean the class in which I want to call the interface?

Comment: @zolty13 yes, I have `services.AddTransient<IUserData, UserData>();`

Comment: `(UserData)UserData` is a weird and  unnecessary typecast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point in the program, you need to setup dependency injection. This is most common to do in the `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs` by convention.

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
           .AddJsonConfigurationProvider("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
           .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
         services.AddTransient <ISqlDataAccess, SqlDataAccess>(); //Second argument is the implementation of the interface
         services.AddTransient <IUserData, UserData>();
    }
}
```

You need to pass the `ISqlDataAccess` to the constructor of the `UserData` but you had it covered already.

```
public class UserData : IUserData
{
    private readonly ISqlDataAccess _db;

    public UserData(ISqlDataAccess db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
    //...
}
```

Then you need to pass your `IUserData` to your objects via constructors:

```
public class ClassWithIUserDataDependency {
    private IUserData _userData;
    public ClassWithIUserDataDependency (IUserData userData) {
        _userData = userData;
    }

    //rest of the class
}
```

One note: You would need to pass IUserData to all dependency classes. Based on the name, this looks like a POCO object (If it is not, don't mind this comment) If this is a POCO class, or anything representing a DTO or Data, then it is better to separate db from it and allow users to just `new` it. If it is not, you may want to change its name.

Comment: You may want to make that also `private readonly IUserData _userData;`

Comment: @Yamuk, I have updated my question; while it seemed to work at first I soon realized the app would freeze when tring to get to the method from the ``.cs file`. If you could be so kind as to look at it, thanks

Comment: @HenriquePombo Is there a reason why you don't use entity framework? I don't know why it freezes, sorry. But one thing bothered me on line `sql = "Select *from dbo.Users"` Are you positive this works, because `*` is adjacent to `from` without space.

Comment: @Yamuk, I ended up putting the question on another thread and got the answer. It turns out I was missing an await when calling the  Validate(). I am using dapper instead of EF for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2):

In `Startup.cs` you can register your interface and implementation;

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IUserData, Userdata>();
    }
```

Then you can use the interface in a class:

```
public class TestClass{
  private IUserData _userData;
  public TestClass(IUserData userdata){
    _userData = userdata;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I totally missed out on simply just simply introduce the interface variable on the `.cs file`; thanks