# Call to DB gets stuck on await (but works when called from a Blazor component)

Tags: asynchronous, blazor, blazor-server-side

When calling the method from the `.cs file`, the app gets stuck on the await line; but if I call it from the `.razor` it works flawlessy.

**.cs**

```
public AccountService(IUserData userData)
{
    _userData = userData;
}
...
public async Task<bool> Validate(string userId, string password)
{
    ...
    try
    {
        List<UserModel> users = new List<UserModel<();
        users = await _userData.GetUsers();
        //NEVER GETS HERE
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

**.razor**

```
@inject IUserData _db;

@code {
    private List<UserModel> users;
    ...
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        users = await _db.GetUsers();
    }
    ...
```

**UserData**

```
    public class UserData : IUserData
    {
        private readonly ISqlDataAccess _db;

        public UserData(ISqlDataAccess db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public Task<List<UserModel>> GetUsers()
        {
            string sql = "Select *from dbo.Users";
            return _db.LoadData<UserModel, dynamic>(sql, new { });
    }
    ...
}
```

**IUserData**

```
    public interface IUserData
    {
        Task<List<UserModel>> GetUsers();
        ...
    }
```

**DBAccess**

```
        public async Task<List<T>> LoadData<T, U>(string sql, U parameters)
        {
            string connectionString = _config.GetConnectionString(ConnectionStringName);

            using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                var data = await connection.QueryAsync<T>(sql, parameters); //I GET STUCK HERE
                return data.ToList();
            }
        }
```

**IDBAccess**

```
Task<List<T>> LoadData<T, U>(string sql, U parameters);
```

**PS**
I updated this post `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68225154/implementing-an-interface-on-a-class-with-dependency-injection` with this question, but sinced I had already marked it as answered I decided to make a new one

Comment: How and Where do you call Validate() ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'm calling Validate from a component like this: `if(((AccountService)AccountService).Validate(user.UserCredentials, user.Password).Result)`. The .Result may seem weird, but otherwise I get an error: can't convert ...Task<bool> to bool

Comment: Please can you define what cs file when you say, *When calling the method from the .cs file, the app gets stuck on the await line;* Is it a helper class, a service or a component?  It looks like it's a service, in which case what type of service is it and what type of service is `IUserData`?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis It is a service.

Comment: See second half of question then.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis, what do you mean by type of service? And, not meaning to be rude, but is that relevant to the question?

Comment: No Problem. Singleton, Scoped or Transient for each.

Comment: IDBAccess-> Transient;   IUserData-> Transient;  AccountService->Scoped

Comment: `((AccountService)AccountService).Validate(...)` should just be `AccountService.Validate(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is how your code is *calling* the asynchronous method:

```
if (((AccountService)AccountService).Validate(user.UserCredentials, user.Password).Result)
```

> The .Result may seem weird, but otherwise I get an error: can't convert ...Task to bool

The proper solution for this error is to [use `await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#async-all-the-way), not `Result`:

```
if (await ((AccountService)AccountService).Validate(user.UserCredentials, user.Password))
```

[Using `Result` can cause deadlocks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).